# How to restrict user from updating same row twice+

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a system similar to a Facebook LIKE button. I want to allow a user to like a picture, but only let them like it once. After they have liked it, they should only be able to unlike it.

My current code is:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["picID"];

    include 'db.php';

    $colID  = str_replace('_', ' ', $_GET['picID']);
    $colID  = mysql_escape_string($picID);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM picture WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()."<br/>".sql); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    $update = "UPDATE picture SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($update) or die (mysql_error()."<br/>".update);     
    echo "Thank you";

?>
```

Currently I use a hyperlink to trigger the 'Like' action:

```
<a href='like.php?colID=$row[id]'>Like</a>
```

At the end I'd like to change this to AJAX so the user can simply click Like (as on Facebook) without any page change. I'm still reading up on how to do this. Is there a particular name for this task? Or can someone show me show I could do this?

**EDIT:**

The user needs to be logged in to be able to like a picture. I have two unlinked tables, `User` and `Pictures`. Currently a user can just keep clicking 'Like' and it adds 1 to the like column.

Comment: set a conditional (if/else) statement

Comment: Could you elaborate? Currently a user is required to be logged in to 'Like' a picture - Their user is added to the database using their session state.

Comment: you would have to record every single like as a separate record, otherwise you'll have absolutely NO way of telling who's like something or not. e.g. if `likes` is 203, how can you tell if user X was someone who contributed a +1 to that total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to create a table that contains columns for picture IDs and user IDs to show that a person has liked a particular picture. If a user ID is listed in the table with a picture ID, then you should not allow them to like the picture since they have already liked it. You can perform this check with a query to the database that will return a count of a 1 or a 0.

Comment: so each picture would have it's own table? Or each user would have their own table of 'liked' pictures (IDs)

Comment: You would create a new table called "likes", and in that table each like would have an "Image ID" and "User ID" column. Then when you need to know how many likes an image has, you tally all the likes for that Image ID in the likes table.

Answer (score 0):

Make a string column in your database to indicate who liked the picture.

If the user is logged in (so can vote), search his name in the string by exploding it and looping it. Then remove his name from the string or add it. 
*Note that you could also save the array directly to the database using serialization:* http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

For a fast loading, you could have an other column with the count of names of the first columns.